# Div height does not meet the height of contents

Tags: css

I'm trying to auto adjust the height of the main div but i cant get it to work. I've put in 620px so you can see the content but would like to make it fit it's contents.

CSS code:

```
#distributors {
}

#distributors input {
    height: 2.5em;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#distributors input.visible {
    visibility: visible !important;
}

#distributors label {
    background: #f9f9f9; 
    border-radius: .25em .25em 0 0;
    color: #888;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 2.5em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    margin-right: .25em;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

#distributors input:hover + label {
    background: #ddd; 
    color: #666;
}

#distributors input:checked + label {
    background: #f1f1f1; 
    color: #444;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 6;
    /*
    -webkit-transition: .1s;
    -moz-transition: .1s;
    -o-transition: .1s;
    -ms-transition: .1s;
    */
}

#content {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 0 .25em .25em .25em;
    min-height: 20em;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 620px;
    z-index: 5;
}

#content .store-card {
    min-height: 240px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#content .store-card img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#content .store-card h4 {
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#content .store-card p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#content .store-card a {
    font-weight: 700;
}

#content-1, #content-2, #content-3, #content-4 {
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: -100;
    transition: all linear 0.3s;
}

#distributors input#tab-1:checked ~ #content #content-1,
#distributors input#tab-2:checked ~ #content #content-2,
#distributors input#tab-3:checked ~ #content #content-3,
#distributors input#tab-4:checked ~ #content #content-4 {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Please check following jsfiddle and fix if possible:
https://jsfiddle.net/uydomdub/

Comment: so you used height: auto; and it didnt work?

Comment: Just remove the `height` property or give `height: auto;`

Comment: @nashcheez and keith won't work as the content is absolutely positioned - if you look at the fiddle and actually try what you suggest, you would see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the absolute positioning from your child content divs, change the last styles in your fiddle and remove the fixed height from the content div:

```css
#content-1,
#content-2,
#content-3,
#content-4 {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 1.5em;
  display: none;
  transition: all linear 0.3s;
}

#distributors input#tab-1:checked ~ #content #content-1,
#distributors input#tab-2:checked ~ #content #content-2,
#distributors input#tab-3:checked ~ #content #content-3,
#distributors input#tab-4:checked ~ #content #content-4 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  display:block;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uydomdub/2/)